# How can I circumvent an “Unable to open channel, funding amount is too large” error?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels, ln-channel-balance-management

Getting this error when trying to open a channel with an existing peer:

```
Unable to open channel, funding amount is too large, the max channel size is: 0.16777215 BTC
```

1. Where is this limit set up and why is there?
2. Is there a way to allow the creation of a 'large' channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same/similar issue check if `protocol.wumbo-channels=true` is under the protocol section of your lnd configuration file:

```
[protocol]
; // If set, then lnd will create and accept requests for channels larger than 0.16 BTC
; protocol.wumbo-channels=true
```

If not there, this look is a default setting in LND nodes, to change this settings you need to add protocol.wumbo-channels=true

```
$ sudo vi /mnt/hdd/lnd/lnd.conf
```

Then you need to restart LND

```
$ sudo systemctl restart lnd
```

You can keep an eye on LND logs as it restarts

```
$ sudo journalctl -f -u lnd
```

- YOU HAVE TO WAIT A FEW MINUTES BEFORE TRYING AGAIN TO OPEN A CHANNEL AS YOUR LND WILL HAVE TO RECONNECT TO ALL ITS PEERS *

**Then open your faaaat channel**